# The mesh on the elbow gets weird after moving the arm bone

Tags: mesh, bones

I got this model from a web and i wanted to do a pose for the caracter by myself but when i rotate the arm, the elbow gets weird.

[image]

[image]

There's another bone for the elbow but i don't kno if i'm moving the arm wrong or what.

Thx

Comment: Hello. It would help to see the mesh topology, the weights, and the bones. Can you share the model or the download link where you got it from? Or can you add screenshots at least?

Comment: @Blunder Yeah sure https://www.models-resource.com/wii_u/thelegendofzeldabreathofthewild/model/20367/ https://www.models-resource.com/wii_u/thelegendofzeldabreathofthewild/model/20402/ The first one is from link's body and the second one is the one im using in the screenshots, the shirt

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the links. To me, the bent elbow looks fine. I think you just bent it straight down, didn't you? To create the pose shown in your 2nd screenshot, you need to bend the elbow to the front along the global Z-axis, and then rotate the shoulder bone also to the front (along the global Y-axis) as you would do it with your own arm. I think it's the *Arm_1_R* bone, IIRC. Have you done this?